# Blurry font on Firefox, Opera

Tags: firefox, fonts

I need to fix blurry font only on Firefox.
I changed fonts settings using:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings hinting full
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings antialiasing none
```

Fonts are ok everywhere else except for Firefox, Opera:

[image: Blurry_fonts_only_on_Firefox]

Comment: "*blurry*" - do you mean antialiasing?

Comment: @Nmath yes, I need sharp letters, without antyaliasing (like in left picture on link below):
https://www.displaydaily.com/images/stories/antialiasing.gif

Comment: This probably doesn't have anything to do with Ubuntu settings or configs but is probably a setting in Firefox.  Have you searched Firefox support/forums?

Answer (score 3):

Try using full hinting in Firefox.

Firefox doesn't use the system font hinting settings, so you have to enable it manually...

1. Remove existing link for `10-hinting-slight.conf -> ../conf.avail/10-hinting-slight.conf`...

   ```
   sudo rm /etc/fonts/conf.d/10-hinting-*.conf
   ```
2. Add new link for `10-hinting-full.conf -> /etc/fonts/conf.avail/10-hinting-full.conf`...

   ```
   sudo ln -sv /etc/fonts/conf.avail/10-hinting-full.conf /etc/fonts/conf.d/
   ```
3. Restart your computer for the changes to take effect. (Loging-out and loging-back-in may also be sufficient).

Comment: Seems to be the same - no changes :-(
Still I can see antialiasing on Firefox and Opera